# Error in Opencv - cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘const CvArr*

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a code to extract yellow color alone from a video feed. After Converting it to HSV i feed that frame in inRangeS Function. I also have a Upperlimit, lower limit and output frame.

This is my code:-

```
cam>>frame;
imshow("Main",frame);
cvtColor(frame,frame,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
imshow("HSV",frame);
cvInRange(frame,cvScalar(20,100,100),cvScalar(30,255,255),redspace);
imshow("Red",redspace);
```

it gives the following error:-

```
error: cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘const CvArr* {aka const void*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void cvInRange(const CvArr*, const CvArr*, const CvArr*, CvArr*)’
cvInRange(frame,cvScalar(20,100,100),cvScalar(30,255,255),redspace);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `cvInRange` function from the old C interface of OpenCV.

If you are using `cv::Mat`, the function [`cv::inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) from the C++ interface has to be used as follows.

```
cv::inRange(frame,cv::Scalar(20,100,100),cv::Scalar(30,255,255),redspace);
```